# How do you remove the counter circles indicating the number of slides on the Bootstrap carousel?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to remove the counter circles at the bottom of the bootstrap carousel. I can't find anything on this. There appears to be a number of modifications one can make to the carousel but little direction on how to do this beyond the limited resources at https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

[Removing arrows in Bootstrap Carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075088/removing-arrows-in-bootstrap-carousel)

was somewhat helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no doubt that there is a better way but here is how I solved it:

I went directly into the angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.tpls.js file and commented out a chunk of code. Please see below:

```
angular.module("uib/template/carousel/carousel.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("uib/template/carousel/carousel.html",
    "<div ng-mouseenter=\"pause()\" ng-mouseleave=\"play()\" class=\"carousel\" ng-swipe-right=\"prev()\" ng-swipe-left=\"next()\">\n" +
    "  <div class=\"carousel-inner\" ng-transclude></div>\n" +
    "  <a role=\"button\" href class=\"left carousel-control\" ng-click=\"prev()\" ng-class=\"{ disabled: isPrevDisabled() }\" ng-show=\"slides.length > 1\">\n" +
    "    <span aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left\"></span>\n" +
    "    <span class=\"sr-only\">previous</span>\n" +
    "  </a>\n" +
    "  <a role=\"button\" href class=\"right carousel-control\" ng-click=\"next()\" ng-class=\"{ disabled: isNextDisabled() }\" ng-show=\"slides.length > 1\">\n" +
    "    <span aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right\"></span>\n" +
    "    <span class=\"sr-only\">next</span>\n" +
    "  </a>\n" +
    // "  <ol class=\"carousel-indicators\" ng-show=\"slides.length > 1\">\n" +
    // "    <li ng-repeat=\"slide in slides | orderBy:indexOfSlide track by $index\" ng-class=\"{ active: isActive(slide) }\" ng-click=\"select(slide)\">\n" +
    // "      <span class=\"sr-only\">slide {{ $index + 1 }} of {{ slides.length }}<span ng-if=\"isActive(slide)\">, currently active</span></span>\n" +
    // "    </li>\n" +
    // "  </ol>\n" +
    "</div>\n" +
    "");
}]);
```

There appears to be no other side-effects save that I was able to remove the counter circles from the bottom of the slider.